# Trying to add bmp image to ScrolledText widget and it says it does not exist (Tkinter)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to add a program icon I got as a bmp image to a `ScrolledText` widget. I'm getting this error:

> _tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.BmpImagePlugin.BmpImageFile image mode=RGB size=32x32 at 0x19B2FA18EB0>" doesn't exist

Here's the relevant code:

```
def get_icon(exe):
    ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
    ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)

    large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(exe, 0)
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ico_x, ico_y)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

    hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)
    hdc.DrawIcon((0, 0), large[0])

    hbmp.SaveBitmapFile(hdc, 'icon.bmp')

    img = Image.open("icon.bmp")

    return img

text_area = ScrolledText(root,
                            width = 40,
                            height = 40,
                            font = ("Times New Roman",
                                    25))

img = get_icon("C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\Brave.exe")
text_area.image_create("current", padx=5, pady=5, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img))
text_area.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.5, anchor='s')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have multiple instances of `tk.Tk()`, try adding `master=text_area` to the `ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`

Comment: @TheLizzard I only have one instance and it's root.

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the `PhotoImage` object for it to continue to exist - as a global variable, for example.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper I did that and now it doesn't give any errors. Unfortunately, the image does not appear.

Comment: Try using reference and other coordinates for place(e.g. `relx=0.5, rely=0.5`), or `pack()`.